# jQuery get all elements inside SVG with ID specified

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg

I use [this jQuery plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) to load SVG image into a div. I'd like to get all the element IDs from the SVG XML data which contain an ID attribute. For example, in my SVG image I have `circle` and `polygon` elements with ID attributes, but a `rect` element without ID attribute. I want to get these two with IDs from the XML.

How do I do this?

I have tried this in the `onLoad` method of `svg` function.

```
$("#image svg").each(function() {
    $("#list").append("<option>" + this.id + "</option>");
});
```

`#image` is the container for the `svg` element and `#list` is the `select` tag.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. We are happy to help you with the code you have.

Comment: @FelixKling I added the code I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the SVG is added to the page properly, you can use the ["has attribute selector"](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to select all elements with an ID:

```
$("#imag > svg [id]").each(function() {
    $("#list").append("<option>" + this.id + "</option>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not working?

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/y6bRC/1/) with your code

```
$("#image svg").each(function() {
    $("#list").append("<option>" + this.id + "</option>");
});
```

and it looks fine to me.

Edit: Replace the second line with this:

```
$("#list").append("<option style='display:" + ((this.id.length>0)?'inline':'none') + ";'>" + this.id + "</option>");
```

to show only the ones with the ID. Or just put a check(length>0, or something) before appending the option tag(which would probably be easier to understand/modify later on, I just like to use ternary operators :p )

Comment: I meant something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/y6bRC/2/ I need to fetch all the IDs and parse only the ones I want: rect, polygon and circle.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your edit, too. This one might not list items without ID, but it still loops over `svg` elements in `#image`, not elements in `svg`.

Comment: @MikkoP You're using the wrong selector. In the first line, it should be $('#image g') OR $('#image svg *') and not svg
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/y6bRC/3/)